# Sql server backup with password

Tags: sql-server-2005, encryption, passwords

When we backup data in SQL server, i want a way to password protect it. Is there a way to do this without using third party tools ?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Backup encryption is not supported out of the box, even in SQL Server 2008.

Redgate's [SQL Backup](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Backup/) supports it.

Answer (score 1):

Until the next version, you have a basic password option for [BACKUP DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx). However...

> The protection provided by this
>   password is weak. It is intended to
>   prevent an incorrect restore using SQL
>   Server tools by authorized or
>   unauthorized users. It does not
>   prevent the reading of the backup data
>   by other means or the replacement of
>   the password.

...so it's not very good, so use the 3rd party tools from [Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Backup/index.htm) or [Quest](http://www.quest.com/litespeed-for-sql-server/)